# suffix and infix searches in SharePoint 2010 using keywordquery search

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-scope, keywordquery

Is there a way to perform suffix or infix search in SharePoint 2010 using KeywordQuery search?

I want to search my site using scopes. I am using Property Restrictions and wildcards but i cannot perform a search like say, `Restaurant LIKE '%McDonalds%'`, which is possible in case of `FullTextSqlQuery`.